# Change the column's content of a query result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

Here is the kind of result I have after executing my request.

```
Category

K
O
I
P
Q
K
```

Here is the kind of result I need.

```
Category

Key
Non-Key
Intercompany
Non-Key
Non-Key
Key
```

I don't care if it is ordered or not. To do this I have this xml file.

```
<BPCategories>
<BPCategory name="Core">
    <type value ="C"/>
</BPCategory>
<BPCategory name="Intercompany">
    <type value="I"/>
</BPCategory>
<BPCategory name = "Key">
    <type value="K"/>
</BPCategory>
<BPCategory name = "Non-Key">
    <type value="0"/>
    <type value="_"/>
    <type value="L"/>
    <type value="N"/>
    <type value="O"/>
    <type value="P"/>
    <type value="Q"/>
    <type value="S"/>
    <type value="V"/>
</BPCategory>
<BPCategory name="WOV">
    <type value="W"/>
</BPCategory>
</BPCategories>
```

So my question is, Is it possible to do it within an sql query ? You must know that I don't have a table to do the correspondence between the categories. Even if it is possible, Is it not better to do it by doing a for loop on the result set to change the values. In fact I'm looking for the best way to do this in c#.

Thanks in advance ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do that with a `CASE` in your select statement

```
Select
CASE Category
WHEN 'K' THEN 'Key'
WHEN 'O' THEN 'Non-Key'
WHEN 'I' THEN 'InterCompany'
WHEN 'P' THEN 'Non-Key'
WHEN 'Q' THEN 'Non-Key'
WHEN 'K' THEN 'Key'
END as Category
FROM ...
```

assuming this is MS-SQL server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look into a SQL CASE expression

Comment: I know the CASE expression but it is the best way to do it ? In fact my query is about 40 lines and it will be tricky to include a CASE expression generated by the xml in this query. There are no other ways ? What about performance ?